# Get all users for the Azure AD group in Azure CLI - 100 limit issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I'm looking for a way to retrieve information about all users that belong to a particular group and store the results in CSV.
So, I use the following Azure AD command for the purpose:

```
Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "xxx" | get-azureaduser | Export-Csv -nti users.csv
```

However, the command only returns 100 users maximum.
Is there a way to return all the users that belong to a group from the CLI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try  `Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId "xxx" -all $true | ...`

Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadgroupmember?view=azureadps-2.0 for reference

Answer (score 1):

Using PowerShell, you can add the parameter `-top xxx` (`-top 500` for example), or `-all` for all group members.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-AzADUser` instead!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you expand your answer to include an example (with full syntax) of how to use this command?